# Git autocompletion with WSL "Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal"

Tags: git, shell, terminal, autocomplete, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Autocompletion work well with all command except when I start my command line with `git`. When I'm trying to autocomplete command line with `tab` key, my shell trigger this error :

> Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.

I've seen lot's of trouble arround this error, but every error was about `ssh` command and I'm not running ssh in this case.

Is there any stuff to find at least, the problem, or just when this error is triggered, in which file, command, package, ...?

All version used:

- **WSL2** is running **Ubuntu 20.04**, with original OS **Windows 11**
- Git version **2.25.1**
- **bash-completion** package installed
- Terminal used is [**Hyper.js 3.2.0**](https://hyper.is/)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: That's an ssh message, you've got something preprocessing what you type and internally issuing a remote command when it's git. You're going to need to give more details of what you're doing, don't just name the tools you use, show exactly what you're doing with them.

Comment: Given that this occurs *when you press the TAB key*, it's clear that what is happening is whatever autocompletion software you're using, that *software* is running `ssh` for some reason. What software you're using is therefore the next question; "bash-completion package" could be any number of collections of different autocompletion software.

Comment: It seems it trying to connect to one of my known machine, `ssh` is called there. I need now to find which process is triggering this ssh call. Because the ssh target is my own server, I'm betting on a home made script that my mind can't remember... I'll investigate and be back. Thanks for the clue.

Answer (score 0):

As illustrated in [rprichard/wslbridge issue 45](https://github.com/rprichard/wslbridge/issues/45), you might need to configure Hyper.js to use [`wslbridge2`](https://github.com/Biswa96/wslbridge2) instead.

> For recent changes in WSL, particularly WSL mode V2, the new gateway wslbridge2 should be used instead.

This old [`vercel/hyper` issue 1127](https://github.com/vercel/hyper/issues/1127#issuecomment-274322582=) showed how to set wslbridge.  It can be adapted to use wslbridge2.